# Why is sudo bash different from regular bash

Tags: scripts, environment-variables

**Problem description** :  I am using something called *play framework* in my development which requires me to make the python script **play** available in the path. Hence I create a symbolic link in **/usr/local/bin** ... Now I have written a shell script (call it **status.sh**) which calls this python script as follows : `play status <some values here related to my app> &> /tmp/xyz.txt` and this shell script then sends me the file via email. This works perfectly when I execute the script as follows `./script.sh`. However when the script is executed as a cron expression everyday I get an output from stderr saying 'play: command not found'.

Hence I did some digging on my own and here are my findings :

1. `echo $PATH` when I am on the shell shows that I have **/usr/local/bin** available to me hence I can successfully execute the command `play status`
2. however when I type in `sudo bash` and then `echo $PATH` I do not have the path **/usr/local/bin** anymore. It is a limited set of folders (one of them being **/usr/bin**).

**Q** : Why this behavior ?! I fail to understand why the path is different. Also as a workaround would you suggest I do :

- new symbolic link from **/usr/bin** to **/usr/local/bin** (what are the side effects of this?)
- remove **/usr/local/bin** sym link altogether and only use **/usr/bin**
- is there a convention that I am not following here for linking new programs and executing them from `$PATH` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All users, including root, have a set of environment variables that are applied each time a new shell is opened.

For a normal user you can add to the existing path by editing ~/.bashrc and putting the followling line at the very end:

```
PATH=$PATH:/mypath_to_my_files
```

For root I believe you would have to edit /root/.bashrc instead.  In this case however it probably makes sense to make sure that *all* users have this in their path and for this you can use the edit line above and just put it at the end of the file /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: But if i am logged in as **root** user, what difference does it make if I execute `sudo bash` ? Am I already not the root user? What additional privileges does this provide?!

Comment: and if the **root** user has the path **/usr/local/bin** in the ENV variable, why does the cron job running execute with the privileges similar to that of *sudo bash* ?

Comment: No, you're not the root user, you're an admin user which is a normal user with admin privileges.  As soon as you type "sudo bash" it invokes another shell as root.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you simply move the symbolic link to /usr/bin.

Comment: whats would be the effect of linking **/usr/bin/play** to point to **/usr/local/bin/play** ?

Comment: Also, what would be the effect of having **/usr/bin/play** and **/usr/local/bin/play** sym link to **/root/play-folder/play-script** ?

Comment: I was thinking that you should just have the symbolic link to play in /usr/bin/play since having it in both places would be pointless if everyone has /usr/bin in their path.